# where to find appid

Tags: facebook-authentication, app-id

I registered my website in hopes to enable the facebook login script on my site, but after registration i was sent directly to the webapps page. Under the authentification section of the websites section it says I'll need my appid when filling out the form. But it doesn't say where I'm to find my appid. I can't seem to find it. Am I suppose to create a new app?

Answer (score 0):

You must first register for a Facebook application at http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php. Once you have created an application, you will have an application page: `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=12345`. The number is place of 12345 is your application's ID.